# ¿Cómo añadir un StyledEditorKit a un JComboBox en Java?

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo añadir la clase StyledEditorKit a un JCombobox?
Quisiera poder cambiar el tamaño de letra de un texto dentro de un JTextPane y los tamaños están cargados dentro de un JComboBox.
Tengo algo así:

```
String tamano[] = {"12","13","14"};
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(tamano);

cb.addActionListener(StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction("cambiar", Integer.paraseInt((String) cb.getSelectedItem)));
```

pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que tratas de cambiar el tamaño del texto dependiendo del valor definido en el [JComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html), para realizarlo seria de la siguiente forma:

```
    String tamano[] = {"12","13","14"};
    JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(tamano);

  //  cb.addActionListener(StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction("cambiar", Integer.paraseInt((String) cb.getSelectedItem)));


    cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int size = (Integer) cb.getSelectedItem();
                Action fontAction = new StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction(String
                      .valueOf(size), size);
                fontAction.actionPerformed(e); 

         }
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funiono bn

Comment: Excellente Fabian! Saludos!